# CSS scale and transform shows lines in my Chrome browser

Tags: html, css

I want to create for my `<a>` section nice looking smooth zoom-in effect when user points his mouse on it.

It works,but for some reason I have lines between my `<div>` sections inside the `<a>` section.

Here is my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/p1g0Lzu3/23/

So, on hover, there are two gray lines, which I don't want to be there.

I tried various things, but still I can't find the way to fix that.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Have you tried to inspect the page using the developer tools to check why this happens?

Comment: To remve the lines you could use `a {text-decoration: none;}` however your HTML structure is not good.

Comment: @NicoHaase you can find my code on jsfiddle. It's almost impossible to inspect the code, because the animation goes away, when I point to my tools in developer tools section
Azu what do you mean by html structure is not good? still the same, I have lines..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest fix is to give the wrapper the same background color as the divs inside

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #243964;
}
```

Comment: And, taken one step further, once you add the background color to the wrapper itself you no longer need to apply it to all the elements within.

Answer (score 2):

There is something with not setting a height to `.main` class that puts those lines in there. With static position by default, it will try to fill any unfilled space. It's kind of a weird concept but I was able to fix it by adding:

```
 /* additions */
 .main {
   height: 80%;
 }
```

Also, I assume you have the scroll there for a reason so I didn't change that around at all. I added the `media queries` simply for snippet viewing sake. I suggest clicking **full-page**

```css
.container-box {
    transform: translateX(70%);
    display: flex;
    width: 40%;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.shadow-bottom {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 12px 0px 6px #6076a7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 12px 0px -6px #6076a7;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 0px -6px #6076a7;
}


.wrapper {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    
}
    .wrapper:hover {
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    .wrapper > * {
        flex: 1 100%;
    }

.header {
    background: #243964;
    text-align: left;
    color: #dbd6d6;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.hr1 {
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #4990e2;
}

.footer {
    background: #243964;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.main {
    text-align: left;
    background: #243964;
    color: #fefefe;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    height: 200px;
}
.box-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
}
.box-content {
    line-height: 1.9;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #dbd6d6;
}
.box-paragraph {
    word-spacing: 4px;
}

.main .footer {
  height: fit-content;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
 /* additions */
 .main {
   height: 80%;
 }
 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
  .container-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .header {
  height: 40px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
    <a href="#" class="wrapper shadow-bottom">
        <header class="header">Header 0</header>
        <article class="main">
            <div class="box-title">Title 0</div>
            <p class="box-content">Some long text here hehehe jsdshsjhdshdsjhd</p>
        </article>
        <footer class="footer">
            <hr class="hr1">
            <div class="learn-more">
               Learn more
            </div>
        </footer>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="wrapper shadow-bottom">
        <header class="header">Header 1</header>
        <article class="main">
            <div class="box-title">Title 1</div>
            <p class="box-content">sdsdsdsd</p>
        </article>
        <footer class="footer">
            <hr class="hr1">
            <div class="learn-more">
                Learn more
            </div>
        </footer>
    </a>
</div>
```

OR check out [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/tkq16v7b/18/)

Answer (score 0):

so, I got another approach for your question, in which you have to change your "height:200px" to "min-height:200px" in 'main' class.

```css
.container-box {
    transform: translateX(70%);
    display: flex;
    width: 40%;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.shadow-bottom {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 12px 0px 6px #6076a7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 12px 0px -6px #6076a7;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 0px -6px #6076a7;
}


.wrapper {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    
}
.wrapper:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);

}

.wrapper > * {
    flex: 1 100%;
}

.header {
    background: #243964;
    text-align: left;
    color: #dbd6d6;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.hr1 {
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #4990e2;
}

.footer {
    background: #243964;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    
}

.main {
    text-align: left;
    background: #243964;
    color: #fefefe;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 200px;
    
}
.box-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
}
.box-content {
    line-height: 1.9;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #dbd6d6;
}
.box-paragraph {
    word-spacing: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-box">
        <a href="#" class="wrapper shadow-bottom">
            <header class="header">Header 0</header>
                <article class="main">
                    <div class="box-title">Title 0</div>
                        <p class="box-content">
                            Some long text here hehehe jsdshsjhdshdsjhd
                        </p>
                </article>
            <footer class="footer">
                <hr class="hr1">
                <div class="learn-more">
                   Learn more
                </div>
            </footer>
        </a>
    
        <a href="#" class="wrapper shadow-bottom">
            <header class="header">Header 1</header>
                <article class="main">
                    <div class="box-title">Title 1</div>
                    <p class="box-content">
                        sdsdsdsd
                    </p>
                </article>
            <footer class="footer">
                <hr class="hr1">
                <div class="learn-more">
                    Learn more
                </div>
            </footer>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```